# Count upper and lowercase letters together in Java

Tags: java, jframe, indexof

Ok! I have this program for class that counts a single character in a string. Whether it is upper or lowercase. The program works if say you type in a string, then ask for the char `'a'`, if there is only a 'A' the count will read zero. If I type 'A' in the char search it will count 1. My problem is I need the char search to count all instances of a character whether it is upper or lowercase, and to count them together as one character count.

Here is the code:

```
package index;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Index extends JFrame
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected JFrame mainFrame;
    protected JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
    protected JPanel panel;
    private JTextArea textSearch;
    private JTextField charSearch;
    private JLabel message1;
    private JLabel message2;
    private char aChar;

    public Index()
    {

        mainFrame = new JFrame("Character Finder");
        mainFrame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        tabbedPane.setBounds(0, 0, 434, 261);

        mainFrame.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane);

        panel = new JPanel();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Index", panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        message1 = new JLabel("Enter text to be search: ");
        message1.setBounds(79, 55, 140, 27);
        panel.add(message1);

        textSearch = new JTextArea();
        textSearch.setBounds(220, 25, 223, 94);
        panel.add(textSearch);

        message2 = new JLabel("Enter a charater: ");
        message2.setBounds(179, 159, 100, 14);
        panel.add(message2);

        charSearch = new JTextField();
        charSearch.setBounds(285, 156, 64, 20);
        panel.add(charSearch);

        mainFrame.setSize(500, 350);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        textSearch.setVisible(true);
        textSearch.setEditable(true);


        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
        {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        TextSearchHandler tHandler = new TextSearchHandler();
        charSearch.addActionListener(tHandler);
    }


class TextSearchHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        int count = 0;
        int current = 0;
        String instring;
        String inChar;


        instring = textSearch.getText();
        if(instring.equals(""))
        {
            instring = ("");
            textSearch.setText("");
        }

        inChar = charSearch.getText();
        if(inChar.equals(""))
        {
            inChar = ("");
            charSearch.setText("");
        }
        current = instring.indexOf(inChar, 0);

        while(current != -1)
        {

            inChar.equalsIgnoreCase(instring);
            aChar = instring.charAt(0);
            current = instring.indexOf(inChar, current + 1);
            count++;
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Character " + "'" + inChar + "'" + " count: "
                    + count++, "Results", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
}
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new Index();
    }

}
```

When I do a char search I have to type twice. I have to type in the uppercase version to count that version, erase that, and then the lowercase version to count that. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String. toUpperCase()` on both the input and the letter you are searching for
Have a look at [tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_touppercase.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You can use String's `equalsIgnoreCase()` method when comparing

Answer (score 1):

I have slightly modified your code to accept user input regarding search ignoring case. If ignore case is checked search is done using a lower case version of a search string and text to be searched. You can modify it and enhance it to your actual need

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Index extends JFrame
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected JFrame mainFrame;
    protected JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
    protected JPanel panel;
    private JTextArea textSearch;
    private JTextField charSearch;
    private JLabel message1;
    private JLabel message2;
    private JCheckBox ignoreCaseCheck;
    public Index()
    {

        mainFrame = new JFrame("Character Finder");
        mainFrame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        tabbedPane.setBounds(0, 0, 434, 261);

        mainFrame.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane);

        panel = new JPanel();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Index", panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        message1 = new JLabel("Enter text to be search: ");
        message1.setBounds(79, 55, 140, 27);
        panel.add(message1);

        textSearch = new JTextArea();
        textSearch.setBounds(220, 25, 223, 94);
        panel.add(textSearch);

        message2 = new JLabel("Enter a charater: ");
        message2.setBounds(179, 159, 100, 14);
        panel.add(message2);

        charSearch = new JTextField();
        charSearch.setBounds(285, 156, 64, 20);
        panel.add(charSearch);

        ignoreCaseCheck = new JCheckBox("Ignore case while search.");
        ignoreCaseCheck.setBounds(179, 176, 200, 20);
        panel.add(ignoreCaseCheck);

        mainFrame.setSize(500, 350);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        textSearch.setVisible(true);
        textSearch.setEditable(true);

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
        {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        TextSearchHandler tHandler = new TextSearchHandler();
        charSearch.addActionListener(tHandler);
    }

    class TextSearchHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            int count = 0;
            int current = 0;
            String instring;
            String inChar;

            instring = ignoreCaseCheck.isSelected() == true ? textSearch.getText().toLowerCase() : textSearch.getText();
            if (instring.equals(""))
            {
                instring = ("");
                textSearch.setText("");
            }

            inChar = ignoreCaseCheck.isSelected() == true ? charSearch.getText().toLowerCase() : charSearch.getText();
            if (inChar.equals(""))
            {
                inChar = ("");
                charSearch.setText("");
            }
            current = instring.indexOf(inChar, 0);

            while (current != -1)
            {

                inChar.equalsIgnoreCase(instring);
                instring.charAt(0);
                current = instring.indexOf(inChar, current + 1);
                count++;
            }

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Character " + "'" + charSearch.getText() + "'" + " count: " + count++, "Results", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Index();
    }

}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys I took took a bit of insight from each of you and I made the following changes.

```
instring = textSearch.getText().toLowerCase();
        if(instring.equals(""))
        {
            instring = ("");
            textSearch.setText("");
        }

        inChar = charSearch.getText().toLowerCase();
        if(inChar.equals(""))
        {
            inChar = ("");
            charSearch.setText("");
        }
        current = instring.indexOf(inChar, 0);

        while(current != -1)
        {

            inChar.equalsIgnoreCase(instring);
            aChar = instring.charAt(0);
            current = instring.indexOf(inChar, current + 1);
            count++;
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Character " + "'" + charSearch.getText() + "'" + " count: "
                    + count++, "Results", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

Now it works perfectly!!! I appreciate it!